# Three-dimensional flat bands and how to create them?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, topology

Consider a three-dimensional non-interacting system with translational invariance.

It is easy to create a two-dimensional flat band by putting this system into a uniform magnetic field. The energy spectrum organizes itself into Landau levels and the energy does not depend on momenta that are perpendicular to the direction of the magnetic field.

Is it possible to create naturally a three-dimensional flat band, i.e. a finite region in 3D momentum space (in continuum or in the Brillouin zone) where the energy is constant?

Of course one can take the mass of the particle to infinity (or equivalently switch off the hopping term in a lattice model). I would like however to have a flat band which covers just a part of momentum space, not the full space. Is it possible to get such a flat band naturally?

Comment: You probably mean flat bands with some nontrivial topological properties, otherwise one can have trivially flat band when all hoppings are turned off. A nearly flat example in 3D was presented in http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.85.041104.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I would like to have a flat band which covers just a part of momentum space, not the full space (see the last paragraph of the modified question). I will read the paper you mentioned.